# Insert Checkbox values into mysql database

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7

I have a query which i use to show data from three tables in dbgrideh. Dbgrideh has field checkbox. When I check the checkbox my program gets an error with the message `cannot insert data into triple table.` how to solve this problem?

I have three tables.

> (table name) first table have fields 'ids, 'name', 'address' with value 1, 'indah', 'jakarta'
>
> (table age) second table have fields 'ida', 'name', 'age' with value 1, 'indah', 10
>
> (table class) third table have fields 'idc', 'name', 'class' with value 1, 'indah', 2

I use one query to select data from three tables like this:

```
SELECT NAME.name, age.age, class.class from name, age, class
```

I Have error like this `Cannot update a complex query with more then one table`

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the details of the error, the query you used and the table schema.

Comment: You need to [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the three table based on the `id` maybe.

Comment: You do not get the error you describe by running the SELECT you show, so it cannot generate the error you describe. (A SELECT does not UPDATE anything, so there is not an *update a complex query* or even a *simple column* in what you describe.) If you want help, provide the actual information, including the UPDATE that you're attempting to complete that is producing the error. A SELECT does not update.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    name.name, age.age, class.class 
FROM
    name 
JOIN
    age
ON name.ids=age.ida
JOIN
    class
ON name.ids=age.idc
```

More about [Mysql JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

---

**UPDATE**:

*you can't insert into multiple tables in one MySQL command. You can however use transactions.*

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO users (username, password)
  VALUES('test', 'test');
INSERT INTO profiles (userid, bio, homepage) 
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'Hello world!', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
COMMIT;
```

More about [Mysql Transations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Comment: You mean update the values of the three table based on the `id`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use following query

```
 SELECT  a.ids, a.name, a.address,
            b.ida,b.name , b.address,
            c.idc,c.name,c.address
    FROM    table name a
            INNER JOIN table age b
                ON a.name = b.name
            INNER JOIN table class c
                ON a.name = c.name
    WHERE   a.name='indah'
```